# Writing to files with Java

Tags: java, file-io

I am currently writing a programming a webserver, I am working on the HTTP PUT method. When the client is connect and he types something like this:

```
PUT /newfile.txt HTTP/1.1
Host: myhost
BODY This text is what has to be written to the new created file
```

I want to be able to write the BODY of the client request into the created file.

This is what I have to far, it work but after I press enter it stays there.

```
InputStream is = conn.getInputStream();
OutputStream fos = Files.newOutputStream(file); 

int count = 0;
int n = 10;

while (count < n) {
        int b = is.read();
        if (b == -1) break;
        fos.write(b);
        ++count;
}

fos.close();
conn.close();
```

Comment: it stays where?  is will not return -1 until the connection input stream is closed

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may try this

```
Scanner sc = new Scanner(is);
```

`Scanner` will enable you to read file easily to a `String`. You may separate BODY using [regex](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/regex/). You just have to provide it as an argument of the `next` method of `Scanner`.

---

After separating, you'll need to write that `String` to the file. Just use

```
FileWriter writer = new FileWriter(file);
writer.write(bodyContentString);
writer.flush();
writer.close();
```

Good luck.